# No puedo cambiar el estilo de un texto en base al state en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

Estuve trabajando en un proyecto el cual es un clone del block de notas de google, que seria el [Google Keep](https://keep.google.com/u/0/), y lo estoy haciendo con `ReactJS` y `Sass`.

Básicamente es una pagina donde hay un formulario, dentro de un componente `Form.js`, compuesto de un `<input>` que es donde se escribe el titulo, un `<textarea>` donde escribo el texto, un botón que al apretarlo publica un componente llamado `Note.js` que seria la nota.

Mi problema es que en cada nota hay una serie de opciones y entre ellas esta la posibilidad de darle estilo solo al texto pero no funcionan como deberían porque la ideas es si por ejemplo aprieto el botón de negrita el texto se pone en **`negrita`** pero cuando lo aprieto de nuevo para que se desactive la **`negrita`** no lo hace y lo mismo sucede con los otros dos botones que sirven para darle un `subrayado` y poner en *`cursiva`* al texto.

Desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo.

```js
//COMPONENTE NOTE.JS

import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Note extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super()
        this.textStyle = React.createRef()
    }

    state= {
        bold: false,
        value: '',
        underline: false,
        italic: false
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        const textRef = this.textStyle.current.style
        const targetedEvent = event.target

        if (targetedEvent.name === "fonts") {
            this.setState({value: targetedEvent.value});
            textRef.fontFamily = this.state.value
        } 
        
        else {
            //ACA ESTA  MI PRIMER PROBLEMA
            this.setState(prevState => {
                let eventState = targetedEvent.ariaLabel === "bold" ? prevState.bold 
                                :targetedEvent.ariaLabel === "underline" ? prevState.underline
                                : prevState.italic 

                return({ [targetedEvent.ariaLabel]: !eventState }) //AQUI ESTA EL PROBLEMA
            })
            
            this.state.bold ? textRef.fontWeight = "bold" : textRef.fontWeight = "none"
            this.state.underline ? textRef.textDecoration = "underline" : textRef.textDecoration = "none"
            this.state.italic ? textRef.fontStyle = "italic" : textRef.fontStyle = "none"
        }    
    }
    
    deleteNote = (event) => {
        let oldNote = event.target.parentNode.parentNode
        let newList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('noteList'))
        let index = newList.findIndex(el => el.text === this.props.text)
        oldNote.remove()
        newList.splice(index, 1)
        localStorage.setItem('noteList', JSON.stringify(newList))
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className= "note" key= {this.props.id}>
                <i className= "fas fa-thumbtack"></i>
                <h2 className= "note-title">{this.props.title}</h2>
                <p className= "note-text" ref= {this.textStyle}>{this.props.text}</p>
                <div className= "option-bar">
                    <select className= "fonts" name="fonts" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                        <option value="montserrat">Montserrat</option>
                        <option value="arial">Arial</option>
                        <option value="roboto">Roboto</option>
                        <option value="calibri">Calibri</option>
                    </select>
                    <i aria-label= "bold" className="fas fa-bold" onClick={this.handleChange}></i>
                    <i aria-label= "underline" className="fas fa-underline" onClick={this.handleChange}></i>
                    <i aria-label= "italic" className="fas fa-italic" onClick={this.handleChange}></i>
                    <i className="fas fa-trash-alt" onClick={this.deleteNote}></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Note
```

Comment: Estoy tratando de analizar tu codigo pero una de las cosas que no entiendo es de donde vienen los `props` veo que los invocas pero no los inicializas en  `constructor()` lo otro es que si definitivamente no estas destructurando `state` en `setState()` correctamente pero no puedo usar el componente si no logro implementar tu componente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` es una función asincrónica, entonces necesitas usar un callback despues para actualizar el style.

Como:

```
this.setState(
        (prevState) => {
          let eventState =
            targetedEvent.ariaLabel === "bold"
              ? prevState.bold
              : targetedEvent.ariaLabel === "underline"
              ? prevState.underline
              : prevState.italic;

          return { [targetedEvent.ariaLabel]: !eventState };
        },
        () => {
          this.state.bold
            ? (textRef.fontWeight = "bold")
            : (textRef.fontWeight = "normal");
          this.state.underline
            ? (textRef.textDecoration = "underline")
            : (textRef.textDecoration = "none");
          this.state.italic
            ? (textRef.fontStyle = "italic")
            : (textRef.fontStyle = "none");
        }
      );
```

Todo aquí: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-bush-3cdfr?file=/src/components/Note.js

Yo también hago un componente con hooks si quieres usar eso.
https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-bush-3cdfr?file=/src/components/NoteConHooks.js

Comment: Gracias ya lo había resuelto pero igual tu respuesta me funciono también